# Gurobi Java model.set(GRB.IntParam.LazyConstraints, 1); throws error

Tags: java, gurobi

I tried to follow some of the Gurobi tutorials using Lazy constraints, but using the method `model.set(GRB.IntParam.LazyConstraints, 1);` as stated in [them](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/examples/tsp_java.html) throws `no suitable method found for set(IntParam,int)` error in static analysis done by Netbeans and also during compilation.

What is the right alternative to that? I am using the Gurobi 6.5.2 for Linux64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version 6, parameters are set on the GRBEnv object, so you must call `model.getEnv().set(GRB.IntParam.LazyConstraints, 1);`.  Starting with version 7, you can set parameters directly on the GRBModel object.